# Is it mandatory for a datagrid to be placed inside the ScrollViewer's ItemsPresenter (through control templates) to support virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have been stuck with this issue for some time now of enabling virtualization in my data grid.
I have a data grid with row details (the size of row details can be huge). CanContentScroll is set to true and Virtualization is enabled.

The problem is whenever a row with huge number of row details are shown, data is cropped (obviously because it doesn't fit in the window size). I cannot afford to turn off virtualization either. I noticed that this can be fixed by directly placing the data grid in the scroll viewer and not to try to fit it in the ItemsPresenter. (Currently i have a style wherein a control template has been defined, default MSDN datagrid style is used). But will doing this again turn off virtualization? How can i verify if virtualization is enabled??

Thanks